# is this program correct to calculate the sum of 5 digits

Tags: c

Program to calculate the sum of five digits
This program is showing error in the compiler even though I think its factually correct

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,a,num=32765,n;
    int sum=0;

    a=num%10; 
    n=num/10;
    sum=sum+a;

    for(i=0;i>4;i++)
    {

        a=n%10;
        n=n/10; 
        sum=sum+a; 


    }

    printf("the sum of five digits is %d", sum); 

}
```

Comment: you've got two `i++`'s in your loop

Comment: Loop is never entered

Comment: No offence, but I take the compilers word on this

Comment: And the error is...? Also, can you please fix the indentation? And ideally pick *one* language, C *or* C++. Please [edit] the questio to put it in better shape.

Comment: correct it please, I'm an absolute beginner

Comment: We cannot post the error which only you can see. Likewise, only you known if you're writing C or C++. And being an absolute beginner does not prevent you from using the preview to see how your question looks.

Comment: compiler says the sum of five digits is 5

Comment: `while(num){sum+=num%10;num/=10;}`

Comment: @peterhuge Are you confusing the compiler (which produces the executable) with your program (the exectuable produced)?

Comment: Change your `for` loop condition and then try!

Comment: Would it work for negative `num`, and what the deuce is `i>=3` supposed to do?

Comment: please re-write the entire code so I can understand it a bit

Comment: Please add the error.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is never entered because i=0 and cant be greater then 3!!! so the solution is:

```
int number=12345;
int total=0;
int remainder=0;

while(number>0){
remainder=number%10;
total=total+remainder;
number=number/10;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile

Comment: @KillzoneKid: If you voted down because this answer has only a code fragment instead of a complete translation unit, that is unduly harsh. An answer does not need to provide a complete program in order to answer a question or solve a problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not at all, I voted down because it woudn't compile https://ideone.com/70iRqd and I am prepared to remove the vote if it is corrected.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: For a single missing semicolon, contributing a helpful comment stating a semicolon was missing or editing the answer to correct it would have been more appropriate than foting down.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, you win! But I cannot undo my vote now unless it is edited again

Answer (score 2):

The loop in your code is never entered because `i=0` and then you check if `i>=3` which is never true.
 You could use something like this:

```
int digit_sum(int num){
int sum=0;
while (num !=0){
 sum += num%10;
  num = num/10;
}
  return sum;
}
int main()
{
int num = 12346;
/*
if (num <0) // add this block if negative number is posible 
    num = -num; // and its ok to change num or use some temp instead
*/
int sum = digit_sum(num);
printf("the sum of five digits is %d",sum);
 return 0;
}
```

Or use recursion:

```
int digit_sum(int num){
if (num) 
   return num%10 + digit_sum(num/10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, just needed correct loop condition. Added comments so that you can see what is going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, a, num = 32765, n;
    int sum = 0;

    // extract 1st digit
    a = num % 10; // a is 5 (% returns the remainder of the division)
    n = num / 10; // n is 3276 (should be 3276.5, but int eats 0.5)
    sum = sum + a; // sum is 5 which is (0 + 5)

    // extract the remaining 4 digits
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) // i is 0, 1, 2, 3 
    {
        a = n % 10; // a is 6, 7, 2, 3
        n = n / 10; // n is 327, 32, 3, 0
        sum = sum + a; // sum is 11, 18, 20, 23
    }

    printf("the sum of five digits is %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/EI9tgM

Comment: “Doesn’t compile” (in C).

Comment: “language:C++14 (gcc 6.3)”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil someone edited the tag, it was posted in c++ section

Comment: The C++ tag was removed 22 minutes before your answer was posted, and the original code included `<stdio.h>`, not `<iostream>`.

Comment: The 3rd iteration doesn't even need a n/10 as its the last digit already. Interesting how none of you noticed

Comment: @peterhuge It is your code man, don't blame me. All I did was the fix of the condition so it produced correct result. By all means feel free to make it better.